# Adding a columnn to count distinct query

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I am trying to get a total number of days worked for employees in a date range.  Query works until another column is added to the select.

Then an error is received:

> column 'TABLE.COLUMNAME' is invalid in the select list because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Where do additional columns get added in the Select, that are not part of the aggregate function?  This is is the query that returns the error.

> select count (distinct PUNCH) as 'Days Worked', EMPLOYEE from
>   TIMESHEET where SUPERVISOR = 'Smith' and PUNCH >= '2017-01-01' AND
>   PUNCH <= '2017-01-31'

Query works fine if the Employee column isn't included

Answer (score 0):

```
select count (distinct PUNCH) as 'Days Worked', EMPLOYEE from TIMESHEET where SUPERVISOR = 'Smith' and PUNCH >= '2017-01-01' AND PUNCH <= '2017-01-31' 
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE
```

Use Group By as suggested by the error.